# Orthoimage to EPSG:4326 - WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, overlay, orthorectification

I'm developing [glrpt](https://github.com/dvdesolve/glrpt) software for reception and decoding satellite images. We already have code that performs fixing of tangential scan distortion (see [here](https://github.com/dvdesolve/glrpt/blob/master/share/doc/rectify-calcs.txt) for algorithm description). I suppose that as a result we're getting so-called orthoimage (or orthorectified image). Example image:
[image: Meteor-M2 image]

My plan is to add geo overlay feature to glrpt (as WXtoIMG provides) and I want to use NaturalEarth database (which is in EPSG:4326 - WGS84 format). However because I'm new to GIS I want to play in qgis to become familiar with GIS theory. I've tried to geo-reference my raster image and overlay ocean layer from NaturalEarth. I've used recommended plugin for that and it asks me about coordinate system for raster image. I've tried to select UTM for northern hemisphere but with no luck - overlaying is wrong, even rotation is wrong. So I wonder how to deal properly with rectified images (orthoimages) from satellites? Could someone give me a hint how to properly perform conversion to EPSG:4326 - WGS84 format and overlay images?

Actually I've realized that it might be simpler to project my shapefiles from NaturalEarth on plane instead. I think after correction of tangential scan distortion I have orthoimage where 1 px corresponds roughly to 1 km on Earth (according to the Meteor-M2's MSU-MR instrument specs). But I can't find any notes about such projection...

**UPDATE:**
Okay, I was able to do rough georeferencing of my orthoimage. Here is the result with ocean and lakes layers from Natural Earth:
[image: georeferenced image]

I understand that I should select more points and do more thorough georeferencing but it will be later a bit. Now I wonder if there are any ways to perform backward transformation so my NE dataset will be warped to fit orthoimage?